# linux web hosting using php to connect to ms sql database -cannot connect

Tags: php, sql-server, linux

I am creating a website for a class project. The website is being hosted on Brinkster level 2 Linux. I am trying to use php commands to access and retrieve information from a ms sql server. The database is stored on Amazon Web Services. The folks at Brinkster swear that I should be able to connect the the database. Here is the code I am using to connect. I have been trying google and the php manual all day.

```
    <html>
  <head>


  </head>

  <body>
   <h1>Connection TEST 2</h1>


<?php
$myServer = "spdm.c4fs80uezapy.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com:1433";
$myUser = "StudentProject";
$myPass = "password";
$myDB = "";

//connection to the database
echo "testing";
$dbhandle = mssql_connect($myServer, $myUser, $myPass)
echo "dbhandle created";
if( $dbhandle ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( mssql_errors(), true));
}


?> 





</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Currently nothing is being shown on the HTML page, not even the "connection test"

Comment: If you're connection to same host, use localhost. If you're connecting to remote host, try to connect with Navicat or PhpMyAdmin from remote with same credentials. Be sure about credentials before finding mistake in code.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add that the database is hosted on Amazon Web Services.

Comment: Any errors? you can try using `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the beginning of your php code to turn error reporting on.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function mssql_connect() in /sites/yuma2/tksheils1/home/public_html/test2.php on line 19

Comment: it seems like you have problem with the mssql module. There might be different reasons, like mssql extension not active, php version issue try searching for the error you are getting, that should help you fix it.

Comment: yeah it seems that the php configuration is missing something. But it is being run on Brinkster's server... There isn't really anything I can change there correct?

Comment: in most cases, a LInux service provider is not going to compile php with M$ SQL support unless they offer it as a service. Those modules are not complied by default. So unless your hosting provider compiles in those modules (And installs FreeTDS and the like for you) or you have enough access to OS instance you are probably out of luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that nothing is shown could mean that there is a parsing error. You seem to have forgotten to end the line with a semicolon at the below line

```
$dbhandle = mssql_connect($myServer, $myUser, $myPass);
```

EDIT: Just saw the error you're getting from the comments. That would mean your server isn't configured to handle `mssql` API. A better option would be to contact your hosting provider customer support about this.

Comment: Yeah I smacked myself about the semicolon when I caught that, but that means that despite what they have told me, Brinkster has not been configured how I need it.

Answer (score 0):

it is unable to understand which databse you are using mysql postgre Mention it
$myDB = ""; (mysql or postgre)